# HtmlBox set_text function does nothing

Tags: html, json, jquery-plugins, jquery

I have some problems with this code? Here is my code that creates text editor from area

```
var box;
...

box = jQuery("#text_vesti").htmlbox({
    toolbars:[
            [
                // Cut, Copy, Paste
                "cut","copy","paste",
                // Undo, Redo
                "undo","redo",
                // Bold, Italic, Underline,
                "bold","italic","underline"
            ],
            [
                // Left, Right, Center, Justify
                "justify","left","center","right",
                // Ordered List, Unordered List
                "ol","ul",
                // Hyperlink, Remove Hyperlink, Image
                "link","unlink","image"

            ],
            [// Show code
                "code",
                // Formats, Font size, Font family, Font color, Font, Background
                "fontsize","fontfamily",
            ],
        ],
        skin:"silver",
        icons:"silk"
});
```

it's create editor and it's all ok, but...in some moment I have to put text in editor to re-edit text and I use this function...

```
    function editujOvo (id){
        editovanje = true;
        id_za_editovanje = id;


        jQuery("#r" + pom).css({"background":"none"});
        jQuery("#r" + id).css({"background":"#dfdfdf"});
        pom = id;

        var podaci = "br=3&id=" + id;
       // alert(podaci);

        jQuery.post("ajax_exe.php", podaci,function(data){
            //alert(data.id);
           // alert(data.naslov);
            alert(data.content);
            document.getElementById("naslov_vesti").value = data.naslov;
            //document.getElementById("text_vesti").value = data.content;
            box=set_text(data.content);
            document.getElementById("date").value = data.datum;

          window.frames["news_page"].location.reload();
        },'json');            
    }
```

but it does nothing, alert just before "set_text" function tels me that data exists and it is in right form and all, but something is missing.... any ideas????

------------ And second question? in this version, or just in mine code, bold button first time does ok, but if I press it to return text to normal, it does nothing, actualy it sets one more pair of `<b></b>` tags around text (it's shown in html preview).. where in code of HtmlBox plugin I can repair this function.... any one???? tnx..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set_text is suposed to be a global function?
i cant se it defined and the htmlbox plugin uses
nice encapsulation so i dont se it having global functions.

maybe the set_text is a method of the box?????
like

```
box.set_text(data.content);
```

where is the set_text function from??

Comment: yes, that is the hint, just before I seen this answer, tried that and it worked.... :)

Comment: box is created like object of textarea with HtmlBox, `set_text()` is the function of HtmlBox plugin and the way to get that function is over `.` like you said `box.set_text(data.content)`.....thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Store object return from jQuery function like that:

```
textbox = $('#texteditor').htmlbox({
toolbars:{...}
})
// don't do that:
function YourClass(){}
YourClass.prototype = {}
YourClass.prototype.set_htmlbox = function(){
  this.hb = $('#texteditor').htmlbox({
    toolbars:{...}
  })
}

// because you can't in future use this field to Ajax.

var save = {
  icon: 'some.png',
  tooltip: 'Save',
  command: function(){
    // context of this function is window!!!
    // DON'T! IT'S INCORRECT!!!
    // this.hb.get_text()
    // this.post("/save")
    // this.get("/text/1")
  }
}
this.hb = $('#texteditor').htmlbox({
  toolbars:{...,save}
})
```

But you may do like that:

```
...
var save = {
  icon: 'some.png',
  tooltip: 'Save',
  command: function(){
    YourClass.hb.get_text()
    YourClass.post("/save")
    YourClass.get("/text/1")
  }
}
YourClass.hb = $('#texteditor').htmlbox({
  toolbars:{...,save}
})
```

Or like that

```
...
var toolname = 'Save'
var save = {
  icon: 'some.png',
  tooltip: toolname,
  command: function(){
  }
}
this.hb = $('#texteditor').htmlbox({
  toolbars:{...,save}
})
var _this = this  // Save context
this.hb.find('input[title='+toolname+']').unbind('click').bind('bind',function(){
  _this // <- use context
})
```